# How to import interface from package

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'd like to import the `Schema$ListMessagesResponse` interface so I can validate the response that's returned.

I tried `import { google, Schema$ListMessagesResponse } from 'googleapis';` but that doesn't work. I'm not familiar with importing this object from the package. It's documented [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/gmail/v1.ts#L474) and [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/gmail/interfaces/Schema$ListMessagesResponse.html) - How do I properly reference it?

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/gmail/interfaces/Schema$Message.html

`Node v12`
`TypeScript 4.3.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to respect the given namespace [`gmail_v1`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/gmail/interfaces/Schema$Message.html#source) exporting the interface

try:

```
import {gmail_v1} from 'googleapis';

const messages: gmail_v1.Schema$ListMessagesResponse = //...
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Much appreciated

Comment: @theartofbeing flagging my answer as "correct" would be much appreciated :)

Comment: better late than never!